# Converting an Excel model to an online model

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I have a large and complex Excel model.  No macros, but 1000s of formulas linking to each other in a giant spreadsheet.  Is it possible to make this an online model using PHP + MYSQL or other programming languages?  In other words, I want to be make the model available for others to use online.

It does not have to look like a giant Excel spreadsheet online but the user should ideally be able to also input assumptions and these would flow through the model and the model would provide the appropriate output.

Comment: duplicate??

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515703/convert-excel-spreadsheet-to-php-script

Comment: Not exactly, I am asking about a slightly different approach here.  It is very important for me to be 100% sure I can achieve what I am trying to achieve before I start trying to create the online model.

Comment: Is it possible to 'emulate' an Excel spreadsheet in a web application? Yes. Is it possible for _you_ to achieve this? No-one here can answer that for you.

Comment: So you want to make a page with thousands upon thousands of textboxes each calling javascript functions by their onchange method to do the calculations that were done in the Excel?

Comment: Google docs has managed it; so, "yes, it is possible". I've done it, but it wasn't performant enough to be usable in the real world; but PHPExcel provides a couple of examples of injecting details passed in from an HTML form and injecting into a spreadsheet with formulae for solving quadratic equations